# Convert frequency Domain data of transducer to time Domain Transfer Function

Tags: matlab, frequency-analysis, transfer-encoding

I have a few .mat files that denote the characteristics of a transducer (transmitter); I want to use the data for my Matlab code, in order to observe the response it will have on my transmit signal.

The first file contains Magnitude of the transducer as follows:  Each row contains the frequency response for one angle. Each column contains the angular response at one frequency.

Similarly, I have another .mat file that contains corresponding phase (in degrees) of the transmit voltage response

The frequencies (in Hz) (corresponding to the rows) are in another matrix given by a third .mat file

and similarly, The angles (in deg) (corresponding to the columns) are in another matrix given by a 4th file.

Can someone help me translate these into a Time Domain representation for a specific angle (using the Magnitude and phase information for a specific angle) and construct a Transfer Function to be used???

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert responses from the frequency domain into the time domain, you need to perform an [inverse Fourier transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). In matlab, this is done with the function [`ifft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html).

Lets consider that you load the data from the first file into the variable `magnitude` and from the second file into variable `phase`. You have to first merge these two variables into a single complex valued matrix

```
f_response = complex(magnitude.*cosd(phase),magnitude.*sind(phase));
```

The `f_response` is the actual response of your transducer, and can be supplied to `ifft` in order to get the time domain response. However there is a complication, the assumed frequency order implied by `ifft`. Although matlab does not provide much details about this, if you check out the [fft docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), you will see that there are two frequency branches returned by `fft`. The frequency responses must be ordered in a way that corresponds to matlab's expected order. If you take, for instance, the first example in the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)

```
Fs = 1000;            % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period
L = 1000;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector
S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
X = S + 2*randn(size(t));
Y = fft(X);
```

The frequency array that corresponds to each of the Fourier transform output `Y` entries is:

```
f = Fs/L*[0:(L/2-1),-L/2:-1];
```

In order to correctly apply the Fourier inverse transformation, you have to check if the order in your frequencies file (lets assume you loaded its contents to the variable `frequencies`) has to be ordered exactly like `f`. Note that `f` has a regular increasing first branch and then makes a discontinuous jump to negative frequencies. The sign of the frequencies is used to represent the propagation direction of travelling waves. If your data only holds positive frequencies, that would be excellent because you would be able to construct the negative frequency branch easily as:

```
[frequencies,ix] = sort(frequencies);
f_response = f_response(:,ix);
f_response = 0.5*[f_response(:,1:end-1),f_response(:,end:-1:2)];
```

and then invert it by doing

```
t_response = ifft(f_response,[],1);
```

Note that, as you want the response for each angle, each row must be inverse transformed. This is achieved with the third input to [`ifft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html).

If your `frequencies` data file has negative frequencies, then you have to order it correctly and then re-order the `f_response` columns accordingly. You would need to upload some sample data for me to be able to help more with that.

Comment: Greatly appreciate all this. I have been working on this. Please bear with me as I am new to MATLAB and DSP. Anyways, I have done this; while seeing the plots, I have realised that these are not band limited, so I have extrapolated the higher and lower frequency values to zero. Still working on this; but would appreciate more help from you. I am not sure as to how, but want to send you the .mat files. email????

Comment: Just to add on, I have files containing the Magnitude, angle and phase responses. Frequencies have not been specified as such. How to go about that? Assume it is a low frequency communication problem, what would you suggest?

Comment: @Sal, look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post) to learn how to add files to your question. Then edit your question to add the mat files so I can take a look at them

Comment: Hi Lucian. I am extremely grateful for pointing me in the right direction. The data had frequencies sorted out; it was in fact a matrix containing data pertaining to radiation pattern of the transducer. By using the Magnitude and phase information, we calculate the frequency domain response in complex form; translating the same through ifft to Time Domain response, and then using any particular frequency and phase information for any given angle, we can select the transducer characteristics we desire..= it was really a simple query but my mind was locked; so thanks for putting me on track.